# Percentage height responsive highchart option not applied on chart load

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In Highcharts, you have the ability to add [responsive](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive) rules to your chart. This can be used in a similar fashion to mediaqueries, where you adjust options for differing screen sizes.

My issue is that the responsive chart option for height is not being applied on initial loading of the chart. I have provided this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scarroll142/b8ogxh9u/19/) to demonstrate the issue. Interestingly, the other responsive rules are being applied. You can see in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scarroll142/b8ogxh9u/19/) that the labels on the xAxis are being shortened to single characters as expected. If you reflow the chart with the button (or resize the view) the chart will get the height rule. Additionally, when the height is set in pixels instead, **the rule applies completely fine**. Having a set height in pixels is not the responsive behavior I need, however.

Below is the same code from the jsfiddle because I have to put something when I link to jsfiddles. Is there something I'm missing here or this a bug that needs submitted to Highcharts? While calling reflow() each time works, it is repainting the chart an extra time and I can't be certain that won't cause an issue with a dynamic layout.

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'column'
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts responsive chart'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Resize the frame to see the axes change'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
        'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
},

yAxis: {
    labels: {
        x: -15
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Items'
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'Sales',
    data: [434, 523, 345, 785, 565, 843, 726, 590, 665, 434, 312, 432]
}],

responsive: {
    rules: [{
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        },
        // Make the labels less space demanding on mobile
        chartOptions: {
            chart: {
                    height: "1000%"
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value.charAt(0);
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 0,
                    y: -2
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
});

$('#reflow').click(function () {
    chart.reflow();
});
```

Comment: Hi @Sam Carroll, This problem looks like a bug, so you can report it on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new As a workaround, you can use the `reflow` method.